# Is it possible to write a getter that takes a parameter?

Tags: actionscript-3, puremvc

I've found two very strange pieces of code in PureMVC's documentation:

```
public function get resultEntry( index:int ) : SearchResultVO
{
    return searchResultAC.getItemAt( index ) as SearchResultVO;
}
```

and bit later:

```
var item:SearchResultVO = searchProxy.resultEntry( 1 );
```

(found in [Best Practices [English]](http://puremvc.org/component/option,com_wrapper/Itemid,174/), bottom of page 38 and top of page 39)

I've always thought that getters must not accept a parameter (and FDT indeed tells me that *"Parameters for getters are not allowed"*), so I wonder what's going on here.

Is that just an unfortunate typo (meant to be simply a normal function without the "get") or some hidden feature/voodoo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the only way to achieve this is as follows:

```
public function getResultEntry( index:int ) : SearchResultVO
{
    return searchResultAC.getItemAt( index ) as SearchResultVO;
}
```

The reason is because **get** is reserved ActionScript keyword. It will in fact expose your function as a public property and expects a predefined format.

It occurs in both strict an non strict type checking modus, so I am guessing that it is a typo in the PureMVC documentation :)

I suggest that you write an email to Cliff Hall then :P

Cheers

Comment: I know, that's why I was asking. ;) PureMVC's doc clearly shows the function declared as a getter but in that case it normally shouldn't be able to accept a parameter. I was just wondering if I was missing something here.

Comment: Maybe when you don't compile in strict mode. I'll have quick try.

Comment: Edited my answer to be more consistent towards your question